# Page rank service

Tags: api, web-services

Given a set of URLs (news articles, blog posts, etc.) how can I rank them in terms of number of backlinks. Is there any service that provides such data?

Requirements: handle 100 URLs/day for up to $30/month.

Comment: Gratis? About how many URLs?

Comment: Many, actually it's not a set it's a stream of URLs. And what is Gratis?

Comment: How many URLs per day? Tens, thousands, millions? Does it need to be free? If not what is your budget?

Comment: 100/day and prefererbly free or up to $30/month

Comment: Could you please put the information from your comments to the body of your answer, thanks!